# Loading .js file in <head>

Tags: javascript

So I am new to javascript (in fact, new to programming in general).

My question is, can I consider loading the .js file in the

```
<head><script src="script.js"></script>...</head>
```

as loading a header file (like in c/c++)?

I guess not. Suppose my script.js looks like this:

```
function copyToClipboard(text) 
{window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);}
```

and my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="a" autofocus="true"></textarea>
<script> onclick=copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("a").value);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It does not work, namely, it does not wait for my clicking (which means that the function is loaded correctly-it is called successfully, it is just that the pop-up does not wait for the mouse event). But if I put the script in-line, it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="a" autofocus="true"></textarea>
<script>onclick=function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard:Ctrl+C,Enter",document.getElementById("a").value);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You were almost there :) Welcome to the world of programming, it's a blast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the first code doesn't work is that you're calling the `copyToClipboard()` function and assigning the return value to the `onclick` variable. In the second code you're correctly assigning it a function reference instead of calling the function immediately.

In other words:

```
onclick = copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("a").value);
```

"Call `copyToClipboard()`, assign return value (`undefined`)  to the `onclick` variable"

```
onclick = function copyToClipboard(text) { ...
```

"Assign a reference to a function called `copyToClipboard()` to the `onclick` variable"

To make it work with the function definition in an external script, wrap the function call in an anonymous function:

```
onclick = function() {
    copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("a").value);
};
```

Comment: I would add that onclick is not setting the click handler for the textarea, but is setting the click handler `window.onclick` for the entire window.  This is because global variables, those without the `var` keyword, are setting properties of `window`.

Comment: Oh, OK, so you mean in the first case I am not returning a "function as an object" whereas in the second case the returned value is a function? That helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: @Paul That's true, but I wasn't sure if that was the intention or not.

Comment: Then my question would be, if I want to wrap it to an external .js file, how should I be able to pass values to the function?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. You're already passing the value of `document.getElementById("a").value` to the function.

Comment: i.e. since onclick = function() {    copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("a").value);}; defined in the .js file cannot accept any argument, so if I were to modify the id "a", the .js file must be updated manually as well, but isn't that defeating the purpose of wrapping a script file?

Comment: Yeah, I still don't get what you're aiming at. If you want to change the code then yes, you need to modify the file where the code is.

Comment: OK, I think that's where my understanding went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All praise the power of javascript to mislead developers into diagnosing their problems incorrectly!

This is not how you define an inline onclick handler. An inline onclick handler is an attribute(or property, as we'll find out in a bit) of an html element:

```
<textarea id="a" autofocus="true" onclick="copyToClipboard(this.textContent)"></textarea>
```

What you did with the `<script>` tag was simply include some javascript code, to be executed as the browser is parsing your html:

`<script> onclick=copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("a").value);</script>` calls your function, and assigns its return value to `onclick`.

But wait, why does your second snippet work?

This is because `onclick` is also a property of dom elements. It also happens that you can assign a click handler to `window` itself - this is what your second snippet is actually doing(thanks to an uncool feature of javascript that attempts to assign to an undefined variable assigns to properties of the global object). That means that no matter *where* you click, your new click handler will be called.

As to your opening question, you can't really say that  tags are like includes - a script can involve more than just declarations and definitions, unlike an included file. You can look into some of the module standards/frameworks, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), for more similar functionality.